# Puppeteer find list of shadowed elements and get list of ElementHandles

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, shadow-dom

I'm running Node 12 along with Puppeteer 2.2.1 (both can't be upgraded right now).

The challenge is to find DOM elements inside shadowed roots and passing them to another function of my main class. Additionally, I'm scraping different websites, so the code has to find shadowed roots dynamically. Using `page.$()` or `page.$$()` I'm not able to check if element has a shadowRoot, using `page.$$eval()` or `page.evaluate()` it seems, I cannot pass back element handles to main function (at least I don't know how to do this).

For example, [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68540701) I'm able to traverse over all elements and find elements with matching criteria, but `evaluate()` returns texts and `evaluateHandle()` returns a `JSHandle` only, which are not iterable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

class Generator {
    main() {
        const url = 'https://www.example.com';
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
        await this.scrape(page);
    }

    async process(page, element) {
        await page.evaluate(element => {
            element.click();
        }, element);
        this.doOtherThingsWithElement(element);
    }

    async scrape(page) {
        const elements = await page.evaluateHandle(() => {
            const walk = root => [
            ...[...root.querySelectorAll('[class*=shadowed-child] button')],
            ...[...root.querySelectorAll('*')]
                .filter(e => e.shadowRoot)
                .flatMap(e => walk(e.shadowRoot))
            ];
            return walk(document);
        });
        // THIS does not work
        for (const element of elements) {
            await this.process(page, element);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access the DOM elements in `for` loop?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48149750/6243352) help answer your question? I think the issue is less the shadow dom and more the fact that you're attempting to return an array of handles from `evaluateHandle`.

Comment: I've seen this already. When passing `elements` to another `evaluate()` I'm still not able to run `this.process(page, element)`. And, sure, the problem is shadow dom, because using `page.$$()` I'm not able to select any shadowed element.

Comment: Let me clarify why it helps. You're trying to return an array of nodes (shadow DOM nodes or otherwise) using `evaluateHandle`, but the return value isn't iterable, as you discovered. As far as I know, the only workaround is to pass the JSHandle back into an `evaluate` and use it as an array from there. So you'll have to adjust your logic to work based on that, or else re-select the DOM nodes on every `process` and take the nth one. The code you've provided is sort of a mock-up, so it's hard to help beyond this--`exposeFunction` could help, but it depends on what the processing entails exactly.

Comment: Potential [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) here. You asked about your proposed solution Y but there's no original problem context X provided, and so there may be a much better solution to X than the Y that you assume. The exact behavior of `doOtherThingsWithElement` may be important--you may not need to work with Puppeteer handles at all. It may be possible to do it all in `evaluate`, possibly with `exposeFunction`s for any Node-specific parts of the task, or maybe the can be retrieved in some other way than the shadow DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I access the DOM elements in for loop?

You can't, as of the time of writing. A JSHandle is not iterable and has no length or indexing capabilities. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48149750/6243352) shows, the only way to work with this JSHandle is to run it through another `evaluate`, at which point the array is accessible:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.1.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
  <h1>foo</h1>
  <h1>bar</h1>
  <h1>baz</h1>
</body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const handle = await page.evaluateHandle(() =>
    document.querySelectorAll("h1")
  );
  const text = await handle.evaluate(els =>
    [...els].map(e => e.textContent)
  );
  console.log(text); // => [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ]
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

It's unimportant that the above example doesn't use shadow roots; the behavior is the same either way:

```js
const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
  <div></div>
<script>
const el = document.querySelector("div");
const root = el.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
el.shadowRoot.innerHTML = \`
  <h1>foo</h1>
  <h1>bar</h1>
  <h1>baz</h1>
\`;
</script>
</body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const handle = await page.evaluateHandle(() =>
    document
      .querySelector("div")
      .shadowRoot
      .querySelectorAll("h1")
  );
  const text = await handle.evaluate(els =>
    [...els].map(e => e.textContent)
  );
  console.log(text); // => [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ]
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

I'll just use the non-shadow root boilerplate for the rest of this post for simplicity, keeping in mind `page.$$` is not an option, which is the primary relevance of the shadow roots to this particular problem.

---

Now, there are some additional workarounds I can offer. These are generic since I'm not sure what your actual use case is, so hopefully you can figure it out from here. One approach is to store the shadow roots in a variable in the DOM, then return the length and use that in a loop:

```js
// ... same boilerplate
const length = await page.evaluate(() => {
  window.nodes = [...document.querySelectorAll("h1")];
  return window.nodes.length;
});

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  const text = await page.evaluate(i =>
    window.nodes[i].textContent, i
  );
  console.log(text);
}
// ...
```

A more naive approach is to just do the traversal and selection every time you need to `evaluate`, which avoids storing the array on the window which can potentially go stale after a mutation or clash with a global.

Taking the approach a step further, you can make an array that works sort of like `page.$$`'s `ElementHandle[]` return value enough for your intended use case:

```js
// ...
const length = await page.evaluate(() => {
  window.nodes = [...document.querySelectorAll("h1")];
  return window.nodes.length;
});
const nodes = await Promise.all([...Array(length)].map((_, i) => 
  page.evaluateHandle(i => window.nodes[i], i)
));

// make up a silly process function
const process = element =>
  // element.click() will now work, but for simplicity:
  element.evaluate(el => el.textContent);

// now go and do the thing you wanted to do originally
for (const node of nodes) {
  console.log(await process(node));
}
// ...
```

Note that `window.nodes` is just an example, probably not the best property to avoid unlikely clashes, and of course replace `window.nodes = [...document.querySelectorAll("h1")];` with your shadow root traversal.

Also, if `length` is large, `const nodes = await Promise.all` might be too much parallelism, in which case you can use a traditional imperative serial loop:

```js
// ...
const nodes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  nodes.push(await page.evaluateHandle(i => window.nodes[i], i));
};

for (const node of nodes) { /* ... */ }
// ...
```

For some use cases, the `:nth-child` CSS pseudoselector can work for indexing as well.

Depending on your use case, `page.exposeFunction` may help too, letting you trigger Node code from the browser context depending on each element you're processing.

Additionally, you may be able to use native DOM functions for clicking and doing whatever else you need to do, avoiding the need to make an array of handles in Node context and keeping all of your activity inside `evaluate`(s).